# A character constant with more then one character

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I was checking some answer I've seen on stackoverflow and altered a line in a way that shouldn't work according to a very experienced programmer, surprisingly it did. can anyone explain why it is possible? 
The issue is a character constant with more then one character (i'm using Visual Studio 2013)

```
// stack.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;


int * foo()
{
    int a = 5;
    return &a;
}

int main()
{
    int* p = foo();
    cout << *p << '  ';  // this line should not compile but it did???
    *p = 8;
    cout << *p << '\n';
}
```

Comment: What are you testing with your code, multi-character literals or undefined behavior? If you only have a question about multi-character literals, remove the rest of the code that causes the undefined behavior, it's not relevant to the question and distracts from the actual question you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can anyone explain why it is possible?

Because the language allows such a thing; it's called a *multicharacter literal*. In the words of C++11 2.14.3/1:

> A multicharacter literal has type `int` and implementation-defined
>   value.

Typically, each character (of a short enough literal) will map to one byte of the `int` value, so that `'ab'` and `'ba'` should have different values; for full details, you'll have to consult your compiler's documentation.